# Can I get text from HTML table using DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have this HTML code. There is table, which was written in HTML code using table, td, tr, th. In the last column there is a mark of student. So, can I get numbers of those students, who has 10 (mark) using DOM?

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
 </head>
 
 <header id="pav"> Lentelės pavadinimas </header>
 
 <body>
  <table>
   <td>
    <tr bgcolor="yellow">
     <th>Nr.</th>
     <th>Vardas, Pavardė</th>
     <th>Grupė</th>
     <th>Kursinio variantas</th>
     <th>Pažymys</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>1</th>
     <th>Vardenis Pavardenis</th>
     <th>MKDf</th>
     <th>1</th>
     <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>2</th>
     <th>Vardenis Pavardenis</th>
     <th>MKDf</th>
     <th>2</th>
     <th>10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>3</th>
     <th>Vardenis Pavardenis</th>
     <th>MKDf</th>
     <th>2</th>
     <th>9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>4</th>
     <th>Vardenis Pavardenis</th>
     <th>MKDf</th>
     <th>-</th>
     <th>-</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>5</th>
     <th>Vardenis Pavardenis</th>
     <th>MKDf</th>
     <th>3</th>
     <th>10</th>
    </tr>
   </td>
  </table>
 </body>
 
 <footer>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="funkcija()">IEŠKOTI</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p id="atsakymas"></p>
 </footer>
 
 <script>
  
 
  function funkcija(){
   document.getElementById("atsakymas").innerHTML = "Maksimumą gavo:";
  }
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery for that kind of tasks:

```
var selectedStudentsIndexes = [];

$('table tr th:eq(4)').each(function()
{
    if ($(this).text() == 10) selectedStudentsIndexes.push($(this).parent().index());
});
```

**selectedStudentsIndexes** array should contain the correct indexes of the students by their original order inside the table